# erbを使用したjavascriptでrailsの変数や関数を使用したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

app/assets/javascripts/*.js.coffee.erbでrailsの関数や変数にアクセスできません。
undefined local variable or methodと怒られます。
具体的にはGET値のparams変数にアクセスしたいのですが、方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2):

Railsからjavascriptに値を渡すということでしたら、viewファイルに下記のように記述すれば出来ます。

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.hoge = '<%= j @hoge %>';
    window.fuga = '<%= j params[:fuga] || "デフォルト値" %>';

    alert(hoge);
    alert(fuga);
<% end %>
```

また、gon という gem を利用することも出来ます。

参考サイト
http://ja.asciicasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript
http://qiita.com/mosa_siru/items/e69eee47a183b13cfb62
http://qiita.com/yk-212/items/8d648b83e24a43af17ba

Answer (score 1):

ありません。

erbはeRubyスクリプトを処理するだけですし、
AssetPipelineは、コンパイル、結合などを経て、圧縮するためのもので
GETクエリ(params変数)で出力結果のコードが変わるようなものではありません。
http://railsdoc.com/asset_pipeline
（もし出来てしまったら。プリコンパイルされたものは、どうなってしまうのでしょう？）

そのような処理が必要な場合は、
そういうviewに、ほんだらだった.js.erbなりを用意して、
scriptタグからクエリ文字列付けて、呼び出すという方法で実装できます。